# apex:include of page in a managed package

Tags: visualforce, package, custom

I have a free app exchange package installed and it allows us to include one of its pages as a page block section on the View Account page.  But we use a custom account view page, so I'd like to put it there instead.

I created VF like this in my custom page:

```
<apex:pageBlock> 
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="RedHot News" columns="1">
        <apex:outputPanel style="overflow:scroll;height:250px;" layout="block">
            <apex:include id="redhotNews" pageName="Rknews__RKRSSNFR_AccountNews" />\ 
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlockSection> 
</apex:pageBlock>
```

But trying to save that fails with the following error message:

```
Error: Method is not visible: [Rknews.RKRSSNFR_AccountNewsController].init()
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Check the Visualforce markup for the included page. It may have a controller or extension that it requires. On yours Visualforce page go to the **Version Settings tab** and ensure the required version of the managed package is selected so the controller/extension can be referenced.

Comment: Thanks, but the Version Settings tab for my page, and the one I'm including, only show the SalesForce.COM API version, not the managed package version.  The first line of their page is: <apex:page id="pg" standardController="Account" extensions="Rknews.RKRSSNFR_AccountNewsController" tabStyle="Account" action="{!init}">  so I'm not sure why this doesn't cause the managed package version # to be displayed

Comment: Can you tell if their `init()` method in Rknews.RKRSSNFR_AccountNewsController is global? I'd expect you also need the managed package referenced in the Version Settings tab so Salesforce knows which version of the package you are working against.

Comment: No, I can't see the code in the managed package, but I suspect it is not marked global.  I was able to use MavensMate to edit my page meta data to add the package version string, but this did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comment discussion, it would appear that the `init()` method in the Rknews.RKRSSNFR_AccountNewsController apex class from the managed package is not [global](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_access_modifiers.htm). As such, your code can't call it regardless of the Version Settings tab configuration.